# how to use the value returned by count function in code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, formview

i know in sql query one can use count function to return the number of rows affected. I need to make a decision on the code behind file using the value returned by my sql select statement.

```
<asp:sqldatasource ID="Sqldatasource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CUSTOMERConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand=
        "SELECT COUNT O.siren, O.siret, O.sap_code, CLIENT.display_name, CLIENT.departement, STATUS.status_lib_fr, PERSONNEL.dbo.EMPLOYES.display, CLIENT.client_id 
        FROM ORGANIZATION AS O INNER JOIN CLIENT ON O.client_id = CLIENT.client_id       
        WHERE (O.siren = @value) OR (O.siret = @value) OR (O.sap_code = @value) OR (O.name1 LIKE '%' + @value + '%') OR (O.name2 LIKE '%' + @value + '%') OR (O.name_other LIKE '%' + @value + '%') OR (O.name_short LIKE '%' + @value + '%') OR (O.name_long LIKE '%' + @value + '%')" > 
     <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtValue" Name="value" PropertyName="Text" 
            Type="String" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtValue" runat="server" Width="164px"/>
```

and so if the values returned by the select command is zero then i need to perform another set of operation in the code behind. but how do one access this value? or is there any other way to determine if the select stmt returned any value or not?
thanks!

Comment: You could add an alias name to the columns being counted such as " count(x.coulumn1) as [column1_count]" and use these column names to check values of the recordset..

Answer (score 2):

Why not put the SQL statement directly in your code-behind file? And better yet, perform a LINQ to SQL query which will spit out a result in the form of `IEnumberable<string>` or something similar dependent on your data that you can play with in all kinds of ways. You can call .Count() on it to see how many records the query returned, or if you just want to test if it is empty, .Any().

This keeps all the data in the C# code behind which you can then send to the page if need be. A sort of cheat sheet for Linq to SQL can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085 and a more lengthy explanation of it can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx.

I recently had to implement Linq to XML in a project of mine having only had experience in SQL, and was impressed by its versatility and ease of use. Definitely worth taking a look at.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the value from `TxtValue.Text`, for example in the `OnPreRender` event handler.

Comment: the txtvalue is the textbox used initially to get en entry from the user based on which the select command runs .